# How to implement multiple timers in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a `timer` for my set of icons which animates these icons. Basically - I have a world map as a background and car,airplane,etc. icons "floating" on this map. I'm using a `swing timer` to do this, but it makes all the icons to appear and start their motion as soon as the `JPanel` is rendered. I want them to appear/start their motion at random time, I thought about implementing a 2nd `timer` and every 10 second create a random number - either 1 or 2 - (e.g and if the number is equal to 1 it starts the animation for this particular icon).

```
Timer timer;
....
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(world_map,0,0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        for (Transportation item : transportations) {
            item.drawTransportation(g);
            g2d.drawLine(item.start_x+25,item.start_y+25,item.finish_x+25,item.finish_y+25);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (Transportation item : transportations) {
            if (item.x > item.finish_x) {
                item.x -= 1;
            }
            else if (item.x < item.finish_x) {
                item.x += 1;
            }

            if (item.y > item.finish_y) {
                item.y -= 1;
            }
            else if (item.y < item.finish_y) {
                item.y += 1;
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void startCoords() {
        for (Transportation item : transportations) {
            item.setMap_coords(map_coords);
            item.setCountries(countries);
        }

        timer = new Timer(10,this);
        timer.start();
    }
```

Comment: Randomise the model - not the `Timer`

Comment: @MadProgrammer How can I do it by randomising the model if I create every object once but I want to randomly spawn them every 10 seconds let's say

Comment: You add another object to your "transportations" List as required.

Comment: @camickr I thought about that too, but I still can't figure out how to add another randomly selected object to my transportations list every 10 seconds, while my timer's delay is set to 10 milliseconds for the animation, and I don't know how to implement a second timer with a delay of 10 seconds

Comment: Not understanding the problem. You create a second Timer with a second ActionListener. If you have a GUI with 3 JButtons. How to you create a unique ActionListener for each button? This is the same concept.

Comment: The idea is the `Timer` is just acting as a pseudo loop.  On each "tick" of the `Timer` you make decisions based on your needs.  For example, you could establish a "anchor point in time" (such as an `Instant`) and on each loop you check the delta between it and now and when some time period changes, you do something about it

Comment: @camickr I get the idea of creating 2 ActionListeners, but I'm thinking over it since you commented and I can't figure out at all how to implement those ActionListeners. Could you please show an example of it with timers, or share some link to some code showing it please?

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` shows how to create an `ActionListener` that you can add to a button. In your case you create the ActionListener to add to the Timer. You find the `ListDemo` code by clicking on the "example index" link found in point 1 of the tutorial.

Comment: @olimpiabaku Looks like you have take the easy approach instead of trying to solve the problem on your own. You really should learn how to create/use multiple ActionListeners in a class. This is very a very basic coding practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Generally" speaking, multiple Swing `Timer`s don't scale well.  And if you're trying to develop a game of some sort, keeping all the "updates" within a single "game loop" adds a lot of benefit when it comes to keeping things under control.

So, this is a really simply concept.  When the `Timer` ticks, it checks for the amount of time which has passed and when some kind of delta is reached, it generates a bunch of "random things".

I also put a little counter in so you can see that something is actually still happening along the way.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>(25);
        private Timer timer;

        private Instant clock;
        private Random rnd = new Random();

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {

                private Instant anchorTime;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    if (anchorTime == null) {
                        anchorTime = Instant.now();
                    }

                    // You could just do a mod 10, but I'm feeling lazy
                    if (Duration.between(anchorTime, Instant.now()).getSeconds() >= 10) {
                        anchorTime = Instant.now();
                        generateRandomThing();
                    }

                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);
            clock = Instant.now();
        }

        protected void generateRandomThing() {
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                int x = 10 + (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * (getWidth() - 20));
                int y = 10 + (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * (getHeight() - 20));
                Point p = new Point(x, y);
                points.add(p);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            clock = Instant.now();
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            timer.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            Duration runTime = Duration.between(clock, Instant.now());
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

            String text = Long.toString(runTime.getSeconds());
            int x = 10;
            int y = 10 + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (Point p : points) {
                g2d.fillOval(p.x - 5, p.y - 5, 10, 10);
            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

This is, by no means, the only approach you can take, it's just one of a question of scalability and control.